# Phonegap / Cordova integration with Bada

Tags: web-applications, cordova, bada, samsung-mobile

Has anyone been successful with the integration of Phonegap in Bada? I am using SDK 2.0.4 and have tried the project app available here (https://github.com/cordova/cordova-bada) but keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.device.uuid') at line 1 loaded from file
```

I don't understand why the Phonegap website indicates that Bada is supported...

Comment: The issue is being tracked here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at https://github.com/imhotep/cordova-wac and try to import it in your Bada 2.0 IDE and deploy it to your device and/or emulator.

It comes with a sample app that should provide you with a starting point

This will ship with Cordova 1.7.0

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The current release of Phonegap / Cordova does not work with Bada 2.0+
They are working on a PhoneGap/Cordova wrapper for the WAC specification http://specs.wacapps.net/ which is supported by Bada 2.0.

You can use SDK 1.2 to build Phonegap apps for Bada. They will work on newer devices too.